# Why does it always give me an error, when I import discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was just trying to write a discord bot on python 3.6.9. Everything was just fine, but suddenly just this error appeared everytime I tried to import discord.py. Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/primzal/Desktop/python/AbfuckBot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "/home/primzal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/home/primzal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 33, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/home/primzal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "/home/primzal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 33, in <module>
    from yarl import URL
  File "/home/primzal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._url import URL, cache_clear, cache_configure, cache_info
  File "/home/primzal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 58, in <module>
    @rewrite_module
  File "/home/primzal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 131, in URL
    _QUOTER = _Quoter(requote=False)
  File "yarl/_quoting.pyx", line 192, in yarl._quoting._Quoter.__init__
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'requote'
```

I already tried to reinstall discord.py, aiohttp and yarl but it didn't work.
Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can I see some code?

Comment: Please add the code, also - what discord.py version are you using?

Comment: This looks like a `yarl` bug. I makes an invalid call to it's own class.

Comment: So there wasn't even code, I was just importing discord.py so just import discord and im using python 3.6.9 and the newest discord.py version

Comment: @BlackTara so just
`import discord
from discord.ext import commands` ? since this like something in yarl

Comment: @AryanGarg Both give the same error

Answer (score 1):

You should install `yarl 1.4.2` using: `pip install -U yarl==1.4.2`